# RegEX match everything outside square brackets

Tags: regex, wordpress, regex-negation

I'm playing around with the WP editor and I'd like to create a RegEX pattern that matches everything outside the square brackets like this:

```
[foo]Some selected text here[/foo]More selected text here
```

And replace with

```
[foo][text_box text="Some selected text here"][/textbox][/foo]
[text_box text="More selected text here"][/textbox]
```

I managed to match the square brackets content using

```
(\[(.*?)\])
```

How can I match everything else?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can your text contain `[`?

If not you can use something in the spirit of

```
((?:\s*\[[^\]]+\])*)([^[]+)((?:\[[^\]]+\]\s*)*)

(                    # first capturing group
    (?:              # non capturing group
        \s*          # might be whitespaces
        \[           # opening [
        [^\]]+       # anything except a closing ]
        \]           # closing ]
    )*               # zero or more times
)
([^[]+)              # store in second capturing group any string that doesn't contain a [
((?:\[[^\]]+\]\s*)*) # catch tags in capture group 3
```

and replace it with

```
$1[text_box text="$2"][/textbox]$3
```

The idea is to catch the text that doesn't contain a `[`. When we stop, we know the next character will a `[`, so this is a tag, so we catch every consecutive `[...]` tags. Afterwards it's text again, so we reapply the pattern.

The "tag capture" before the text will only be used once, if the string starts with tags.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/yE3dH8)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! It won't contain any [] as they will be escaped. I'm making a shortcode generator.

Comment: @GrozavAlexIoan: Woops... Be careful, the old expression was failing when there were two `[foo][foo]` next to each other. Edited.

Comment: I got a question. How can I implement the \G thing in javascript? It seems to work only in php.

Comment: @GrozavAlexIoan Yep, the `\G` anchor doesn't exist in javascript... I edited my answer and the demo

Comment: I really cannnot thank you enough! I can't say how much you've helped me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @GrozavAlexIoan: This is what StackOverflow is about, I'm glad I could help :) On a side note, next time be sure to only accept the answer when you know it completely solves your question: answered question attract less attention and I could have not caught that the first version was buggy.