# Reverse RegEx match

Tags: javascript, regex, reverse

I got regex matching everything in `{ }` brackets, but I want to reverse it, so it does match anything, **except** text inside `{ }`.

My regex now:

```
/{.*?}/g
```

- **text**: Blah blah { hello } world { 1010 }.
- **matched**: `["{ hello }", "{ 1010 }"]`

What I need:

- **text**: Blah blah { hello } world { 1010 }.
- **matched**: `["Blah blah ", " world "]`

Thanks for every suggestion. :)

Comment: Is this [similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152039/regex-match-everything-outside-square-brackets)?

Comment: `s.split(/{.*?}/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get it working with the regex you have using String#split and a filter

String#split can take a regex which will then split your string into an array. filter was due to the empty value at the end because there was a {} at the end of the string.

I set up a demo for you, but I modified the regex to `/{[^}\n]*}/g` so that it doesn't need the non-greedy quantifier.

```js
const regex = /{[^}\n]*}/g;
const text1 = 'Blah blah { hello } world { 1010 }'

console.log(text1.split(regex).filter(val => val))
```